# ERROR:superset.views.core:Unexpected error No module named 'pymysql'

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, apache-superset

I am running apache superset 0.36 in docker with separate dockers for redis and postgres. While trying to connect to MySQL datasource which is running on host machine, I am getting

> ERROR:superset.views.core:Unexpected error No module named 'pymysql'"

I tried bash to superset container `sudo docker run -it superset_superset bash` and then `pip install pymysql` but getting warning

> "WARNING: The directory '/home/superset/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag."

and it does not install pymysql.

Error thrown while running pip install pymysql inside container is

> Installing collected packages: pymysql ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql' Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.

Tried pip install pymysql --user also but same error.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent the error message already show the answer:

```
sudo -H pip install pymysql
```

A pretty reson for `sudo -H`

> When you run sudo your environment is passed along while the effective user switches to root. Your environment includes that your ~/ or home directory (the value of the environment variable HOME) is /home/bijay.

> pip looks for an http cache before downloading packages. Probably for a combination of security, sanity and privacy reasons pip disables the cache so as not to write to a cache directory not owned by the current user. It's just telling you that it did that.

> As it hints, using sudo -H would set the HOME environment variable before executing the command passed to sudo, using root's home directory /root as $HOME instead of your user's. The cache could then be written in /root/.cache/pip/http with no errors.
> As a sidenote, you probably shouldn't be running pip as root anyway.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. For example, why do you need `sudo` here?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for your suggestion! Nico :p

Comment: Tried sudo -H but seems sudo not available inside docker. And while trying to install sudo, getting permission denied error. Here is output: superset@ce311b11ae08:/app$ sudo -H pip install pymysql
bash: sudo: command not found
superset@ce311b11ae08:/app$  apt-get -y install sudo
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `docker-compose`, check out this article: https://preset.io/blog/2020-05-18-install-db-drivers/

Basically, extra packages can be added by adding them to `docker/requirements-local.txt` before running `docker-compose up`.

Note: `requirements-local.txt` is installed into the locally built image: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/Dockerfile-dev#L23